# Solution Factory for Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, line-of-business-app

I love the idea behind [Solution Factory](http://solutionfactory.codeplex.com/releases/view/26598) project. But, unfortunately this project has a few bugs. In addition I don't know if it's the right choice for VS2010, or VS2010 have a add-in that will do it better.

1. Is anyone using it successfully with visual studio 2010?
2. Is there any other better option for the same task? (of creating a new project based on existed one).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an update to solutionfactory that works with 2010 and NuGet (formerly NuPack). It may help you get started with automating solution setups:

http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2010/10/07/using-solution-factory-nupack-to-create-opinionated-visual-studio-solutions.aspx